# database design model

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

lets say we have 3 tables: Cars , People , Companies. we want the owner of the car to be a people (and who is) or a company (and which is). The basic structure of the Cars table is: Car_id, Car_model, Owner_id . which is the best way to do that?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? What do you need help with? Creation statements? Logic? Specific technology/syntax?

Comment: i want the logic to do this. for example i thought to create 2 tables.First "type owner" with the fowling stracture: type_owner_id , type_owner_name. Second table "owners" with the fowlling stature: id, owner_id (people_id or company_id), type owner_id, car_id . But l am think that i am far from ideal..

Comment: Also depends on your business rules, can a car have more than one owner at a time who may either be a person or a company?

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I see two approaches:

- First one is inheritance: Do you have a `car` table and also do you have a `owner`. The `owner` may be a `person` or a `company` both with specific fields and relations.

They are several strategies to [implementing inheritance with standard SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server) and also specific for some dbms vendors. Database Analyst should design best solution for each [domain of discourse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse) and database brand.

- Second approach is to define both foreign keys in your `car` table.

Like this:

```
car_company_owner  int NULL references companies
car_person_owner   int NULL references people
```

then create a rule in database to force your expected behavior. For example you can keep consistence with triggers.